# How to update the height of an item at the top of a <SectionList /> while maintaining scroll position when scrolled down the list?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I have a `<SectionList />` with two sections.

The top section displays an item's description (no header). The second section is a list of items with a sticky header that contains a search field.

The description height can vary between items (ie, different number of lines of text).

```
---------------------------------------------
Section #1
---------------------------------------------

Description (variable height)

---------------------------------------------
Section #2
---------------------------------------------

Search box in sticky header.

---------------------------------------------

Item #1
Item #2
Item #3
...

---------------------------------------------
```

---

*The problem is when you're scrolled down the section list and select a new item, the description height can change and the scroll position will abruptly jump.*

*And my goal is to update the height of the description while maintaining scroll position.*

---

I've tried:

- Updating the scroll position immediately before and immediately after the description height changes. But there's a noticeable jump back and forth.
- Saving the current description height in state, setting the description container to that height with overflow hidden, pre-computing the height of the next description, calculating the next scroll position after description height changes, syncing scroll position to description height (animated value), and then scrolling the section listing to the next position. So we're simultaneously scrolling up or down while changing the description height down or up. This works, but there's not way to use the native driver on height and the experience is janky.
- Use LayoutAnimation to animate the description height changes. This animates the description height changes so the abrupt scroll becomes a smooth scroll. Nicer, but not perfect.

---

Is there a better way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Hmm.. This is not answering your question but you may want to overthink your UI. Changing the content of some cells that are not in the view will definitely confuse your users.

Comment: I mean you explained it like the user scrolls down, clicks something, scrolls up, read the description, scrolls down again, ... How about pushing to new screen with more details about the item or expanding the cell and add the description right into it.

Comment: @JannikS. we might redesign/move the description section actually.

But, in the meantime, wondering if there's a technical fix for the current design :)